# Get all children from parent JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This is an example of my json data

```
[
   {
      "Id":"114",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
   {
      "Id":"115",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
      "Id":"44",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"45",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"50",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Audio"
   },
   {
      "Id":"52",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Configuracion"
   },
   {
      "Id":"70",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Rutas"
   }
]
```

So far I have achieved the following data in console.log:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Padre: "CRM", Hijo: "Argumentarios", Description: "SALUD NORMAL", Id: "114"}
1: {Padre: "Permisos", Hijo: "root", Description: "Usuarios", Id: "44"}
2: {Padre: "Telefonia", Hijo: "Audio", Description: "Locuciones", Id: "50"}
```

I need to show all the children of each parent element. 
I am creating a menu and I want the submenu associated with each parent to appear. I would like the children not to appear repeated. In my json parent it's Padre and Child is Hijo (is in spanish).
This is my original code:

```
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('fake-son.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(menuSubmenu =>{

            const result = [];
            const map = new Map();
            for (const item of menuSubmenu) {
                if(!map.has(item.Padre)){
                    map.set(item.Padre, true);    // set any value to Map

                    result.push({
                        Padre: item.Padre,
                        Hijo: item.Hijo,
                        Description: item.Description,
                        Id:item.Id
                    });
                }
            }
                this.setState({ 
                    menuSubmenu:this.state.menuSubmenu.concat(result)
                })

            console.log(result);         

        })
    }
```

Can you help me show all the children about their father? Thanks a lot

Comment: what is your expectation from your JSON

Comment: I hope that it returns on the one hand each of the parents (menu) and on the other hand each of the children (submenu). In the case of CRM I want you to return CRM and also ALL of your children. The same for other parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array.reduce to create a relation like so,

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      parentList: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //call your rest api here...
    const list = [{
        "Id": "114",
        "Padre": "CRM",
        "Hijo": "Argumentarios"
      },
      {
        "Id": "115",
        "Padre": "CRM",
        "Hijo": "Argumentarios"
      },
      {
        "Id": "44",
        "Padre": "Permisos",
        "Hijo": "root"
      },
      {
        "Id": "45",
        "Padre": "Permisos",
        "Hijo": "root"
      },
      {
        "Id": "50",
        "Padre": "Telefonia",
        "Hijo": "Audio"
      },
      {
        "Id": "52",
        "Padre": "Telefonia",
        "Hijo": "Configuracion"
      },
      {
        "Id": "70",
        "Padre": "Telefonia",
        "Hijo": "Rutas"
      }
    ];
    
    const PadreMap = list.reduce((acc, obj) => {
      if (!acc[obj.Padre]) {
        acc[obj.Padre] = {
          ...obj,
          Hijo: [obj.Hijo]
        };
      } else {
        !acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) && acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Hijo)
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
    
    this.setState({parentList: Object.keys(PadreMap).map((padre) => ({
      name: padre,
      children: PadreMap[padre].Hijo
    }))})
  }

  render() {
    return <div >{
      this.state.parentList.map(parent => <ul>{parent.name}:
      {parent.children.map(hijo => <li>{hijo}</li>)}
      </ul>)
    }< /div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Demo / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
li{
  margin-left: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is causing loss of object as same child name has disregarded but their id are different. for instance CRM has two child relation

Comment: This is perfect, but... How could I show it in my this.setState? Before I used a concat function with const result, like in my original code

Comment: @Casandra Check now, if this helps you.
I am assuming you just need the names and not the id's as arpitsharma pointed out in previous version of my code.

Comment: @Casandra. Never mutate state directly. Always create a new object.
   instead of this`this.state.menuSubmenu.concat(result)`
Else, react wont be able to detect a state change.
You should use,
`this.setState({menuSubmenu: [...this.state.menuSubmenu, ...result]})`

Comment: You're great! Thank you very much, it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can show it by the command `object.toSource()` it show all the object attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following chunk in place of your map code

```
menuSubMenu.forEach((item)=>{
  if(item){
   const key = item.Padre;
   if(!map.get(key)){
     map.set(key,[item]);
  }else{
  map.get(key).push(item); // if you need just child name then push item.Hijo
 }

}  });
```

This code will give you a unique parent map as shown below
For iterating it as array and concat the results

```
let results = Array.from(map);// in results [0] index will have name of parent [1] index will have the array of values
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. I change map1 for map because map1 "is not defined", this is correct? 
How could you show it in my this.setState? Before concact const result. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah I was working on the console so name the key as map1 edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply like:

```
let data=[
   {
      "Id":"114",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
   {
      "Id":"115",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
  {
      "Id":"44",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"45",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"50",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Audio"
   },
   {
      "Id":"52",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Configuracion"
   },
   {
      "Id":"70",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Rutas"
   }
]

const mapChildren=()=>{
  const newData=data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a=Object.assign({},a)
        r[a.Padre] = r[a.Padre] || [];
        r[a.Padre].push(a);
    delete a.Padre;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
  return newData;
}


console.log('#Children:',mapChildren(),typeof(mapChildren()))
console.log('#PArents:',Object.keys(mapChildren()))
```